# Should questions that are related to a typo (syntax error, missing brackets, etc.) be closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

Should this type of question be closed?  In my opinion it does not bring any value to have a question that points to a writing error.

Comment: Yes, of course they should. There's a close reason for them: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced **or a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."*

Comment: @Stijn nope, I didn't close vote at all, just put the comment there. Anyway, the question is closed now.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. There is a specific close reason for that under the *"off-topic because..."* category:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. [...]